# IPXE boot on amd based architecture with NVME

Tags: centos, hp, pxe-boot, kickstart, nvme

We have a quite big infrastructure and now we started to use AMD based servers instead of the intel ones with 1 nvme only for os.

We are using ipxe to kickstart the servers but for some reason with this new amd nvme setup the ipxe fails during the kickstart

Here are the issue that I'm seeing:

https://i.ibb.co/VQksZTF/1.png

https://i.ibb.co/7Gh80BT/2020-09-15-16-34-23-Greenshot.png

Here is the pxelinux and the tftpboot config as well: https://jpst.it/2hIpU

If I type manually the # for grub 2.02

It will kickstart the system, but it should be automated :) somehow it doesn't go to that step.

Comment: Where is your `inst.repo=`?

Comment: you are chaining from iPXE to grub, but have a pxelinux style configuration layout
I would try to only use iPXE, or if you absolutely want to use grub, then only use grub.

Have you made any modifications to your ipxe.efi, or where is it from? (since to work with grub in this way it needs to be compiled with specific configurations)